# Understanding the Bound State Aharonov Bohm Effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge-invariance, gauge, aharonov-bohm

The bound state Arahanov Bohm Effect in most textbooks is addressed by explicitly solving the time-independent S.E. in order to solve for the energies of the system and show that they explicitly depend on the magnetic flux measured in terms of the magnetic flux quanta.

I will refer to a simple example similar to the one treated in Griffiths 3rd Ed Chp Section 4.5. Consider a particle of mass $m$ and charge $e$ confined to move on a ring of radius $R$. There are two modes this particle occupies on the ring, one going clockwise and the other going counterclockwise.
$$ \psi_{\pm} \sim \exp{\pm i \frac{R \sqrt{2mE} }{\hbar} \theta} $$
With energies given by
$$ E_n = \frac{\hbar ^2 n^2 }{2 m R^2} $$
Due to periodic boundary conditions. The plus and minus modes physically correspond to clockwise and counterclockwise angular motion along the ring.

Now, Griffiths makes this example more interesting by introducing a solenoid with some radius $a<R$ in the middle of the ring. The vector potential outside the solenoid is then given (Choosing the gauge $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0$ )
$$ \mathbf{A}(r) = \frac{\Phi}{2 \pi r} \hat{\phi} $$
In cylindrical coordinates, where $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux and $\phi,r$ is the usual cylindrical coordinates. Then one may solve the time-independent S.E to obtain the energies for the new ring-inductor system to be
$$E_n = \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m R^2} \left(n - \frac{e \Phi}{2 \pi c \hbar} \right)^2$$
This is all pretty standard stuff, however, physically it shouldn't be the case that the energy depends on the magnetic vector potential itself as the theory needs to be gauge invariant, and by the way, it seems at the moment, there is energy dependence on $\mathbf{A}$ which is not unique.

This problem will be solved if we demand that the flux be quantized, i.e $\Phi = \frac{2 \pi \hbar}{e} k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, for then the energies are
$$E_n = \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m R^2} (n-k)^2 = \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m R^2} m^2 $$
Where we have substituted $m = n-k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since in the original example with the ring, the $n$'s had no measurable physical significance, we can now just as well say that the positive $m$ modes correspond to counterclockwise motion around the ring and negative m modes to clockwise motion. Thus this quantization makes it as if the magnetic vector potential weren't even there, which makes complete physical sense as there is no magnetic field present to actually affect the measurable energy in some physical way.

In terms of gauge transformations in quantum mechanics, this also makes sense, as if we wanted to solve for the wave function of our particle the S.E would be
$$ E \psi = \frac{1}{2m}\left(p^2 - \frac{e}{c} \mathbf{A}\right)^2 \psi$$
Then if we made a gauge transform allowing us to set $\mathbf{A}$ to 0 we would transform the wavefunction in the following way:
$$ \psi \to \psi \exp{\left[ -\frac{i e}{\hbar c} \int_{\mathcal{O}}^{\mathbf{r}} \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}') \cdot d\mathbf{r'}\right]}$$
If we do this, then the hamiltonian is just the same as one of the particles on the ring with *no* magnetic field!
Note that this is a *smooth* transformation only if the flux is quantized in the units we discussed above. This is because if we then explicitly examine the path integral in the exponential we see
$$\int_{\mathcal{O}}^{\mathbf{r}} \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}') \cdot d \mathbf{r}' = \int_{\theta _0}^{\theta} \frac{\Phi}{2 \pi} d \theta = \Phi \left( \frac{\theta - \theta_0}{2 \pi}\right)$$
The phase factor must be the same at $0$ and $2 \pi$ or else there will exist some sort of discontinuity in the new $\psi$. Enforcing this condition we see precisely as we saw last time
$$\frac{e}{\hbar c} \Phi = 2 \pi k$$
Then we see yet again the same statement
$$\Phi = \frac{2 \pi \hbar c}{e} k$$
Again, this makes *sense*. The energies should not depend on the vector potential as that then makes something inherently observable a gauge *dependent* quantity, and demanding that flux is quantized, allows us to rest easy.

Is this the correct interpretation of the effect? Also, how can we deal with making a "not-smooth" gauge transformation where the flux isn't quantized, will doing this lead us to the same energy dependence as the case where we actually went through and solved the S.E?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but as you wrote "physically it shouldn't be the case that the energy depends on the magnetic vector potential" the $E_n$ shown *is* gauge invariant for it depends explicitly  on $\Phi$ not on $\bf {A}$.

Comment: @hyportnex, That is true, however, the only place the magnetic flux appears is in $\mathbf{A}$ itself, no? If we chose a different gauge where $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} \neq 0$ Then there would necessarily be an additional term wouldn't there?

Comment: At least in Maxwell's equations, the flux is $\Phi = \int \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf s = \int curl \mathbf  {A} \cdot d\mathbf s= \oint \mathbf A \cdot d\mathbf \ell$ and that holds independently of the gauge you set on $\mathbf A$ as long as $\mathbf B = curl \mathbf A$. The expression for the *electric field* changes with respect to $\mathbf A$ and to the scalar potential if you change the gauge.

Comment: My comment is not intended to answer your question, is just a suggestion to rethink it unless I have misunderstood it.

Comment: @hyportnex I see, I will think about this, because you are correct, the path integral should hold independently of the gauge. I think I'm going to work this out again for some general vector potential $\mathbf{A}$ and then examine the energies. Thank you for your comment!